# sql character "\" not valid (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I'm working with DB2 10.5, and I was trying to export a view to excel with the line:

> export to C:\Daten\xxx\DB2010\Results\yyy.xls of del select * from yyy order by zzz

I got the following error:

> The character "\" following "export to C:" is not valid.. SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601

The weird thing about it is, that the exact same syntax worked with the previous version of DB2 (9.7). Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you think the actual SQL code would be important?

Comment: Silly me, thx for the remark... The question is updated

Comment: And how did you issue the `export` command? May be your shell requires you to escape backslashes (the "\" characters)? You could also try using forward slashes instead.

Comment: When I try with the forward slashes, it doesn't say they're not valid. However, I get the error:
'An unexpected token "export to C:/" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601.'

What do you mean by "how did you issue the export command"? I just wrote down the line as is. Do I need to define it somehow?

Comment: Every example I find of a DB2 export command just has a file name.  Try running the command with just yyy.xls and see if it works.  I think you might have to use a .del extension on the file for the export command to work properly.

Comment: Well, may be it's time for @user2742522 to tell us finally what interface he/she uses to issue the command. DB2 CLP? CLPPlus? Data Studio? Some other tool? Custom program?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think you are trying to use the '\' inside a file path. I haven't worked particularly in DB2 but I can tell you that it might be taking "\" as an escape character. Try using "/" or "\ \" (w/o the space) in place of "\". Hope it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither works. With the "\\" I get the same error, and with the "/", it does recognize the front slash as a valid character, however I get another error: 'An unexpected token "export to C:/" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601'.

Thx for your help anyhow!